# Waitforsingleobject to detect a system command exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hi I want to execute a system command for allegro and wait till it completes, since I need to access the files generated by this command. My code is not working. Can someone please help? Is the command not running? It works if I do system(command.c_str()) but does not wait.

```
string command = "start allegro -expert -nographic -s " + fileName1 + " " + boardFile1;

 bool ret;
bool retwait;

STARTUPINFO startupinfo;
GetStartupInfo (&startupinfo);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pro2info;

LPTSTR cmdL = (LPTSTR)command.c_str();
ret = CreateProcess(NULL, cmdL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL,NULL, &startupinfo, &pro2info);

cout<<"hProcess: "<<pro2info.hProcess<<endl;
cout<<"dwProcessId: "<<pro2info.dwProcessId <<endl;

//Want to wait till the command executes

while (retwait= WaitForSingleObject (pro2info.hProcess, INFINITE)!=WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    cout<<"waitprocess:true"<<endl; //The process is finished;

CloseHandle (pro2info.hProcess);
```

Comment: If the command is correct, then the `system` function *should* wait for it to finish, otherwise it would not be able to return the exit status of the command.

Comment: And how do you know that your code "is not working"? What happens when you run it? Don't you check for errors anywhere? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need "start" at the beginning of command, even if you are using the flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. "start" works with `system` (because `system` works with batch command), but if you are creating a new process you should only specify the path to the image file. By the way, the only way to know what's going on is to check the return of `CreateProcess` (and eventually `GetLastError()`).

Also, that's not the best way to use `WaitForSingleObject`. You should catch `WAIT_FAILED` and use `GetLastError()`, otherwise your next post on SO will be: "Why isn't my program waiting?" :-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx